# I am looking for data on election polling locations and more specifically how many people showed up to cast a vote

Tags: elections, polling

With the current debate of mail-in voting vs in-person voting, I want to get a handle on how feasible doing in-person voting would be if adhering to social distancing guidelines. help.

I couldn't find any datasets that would contain that information and wondered if anyone here in this group might help.